# Editing skshapenode's path efficiently

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skshapenode

I have a `SKShapenode` with a path and in the function `update()` I want to add a point so the line moves forward. I am using the following:

```
var path = wave.path as! CGMutablePath()
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: path.currentPoint.x + 2, y: 0 ))
wave.path = path
```

However, when I have more than about 500 nodes the frame rate drops significantly. I think this is because I grab the path, edit it and then put the path back into the shape. Could this be more done more direct and efficient  by **editing the path directly?**

Comment: You could avoid the variable with `(wave.path as! CGMutablePath()).addLine(...)`, but I doubt this is your problem.  `SKShapeNodes` are very inefficient to begin with, and adding to your path adds a lot of complexity.  How often are your shapes mutating?  If it is rare (like 1 shape per frame), then I would recommend only using 1 shape, and convert this as many different `SKSpriteNodes` that you need and just store the `CGPath`s somewhere (Like the sprites `userdata`). When your shape needs a new point,  you could assign it to the path you saved, load it into the shape, and create a new sprite